# Contact Form Domain Blacklists (using java, html or php)

Tags: html, contacts, email-validation, blacklist

I'm using HTML contact forms on a business site to post lead information to Salesforce.  We're using auto-responders to deliver key information to people who complete a form asking for additional information.  The goal is to reject forms that are submitted by competitors.  It doesn't need to be bullet proof; the main idea is to reject and form that has an email address associated with a competitor's domain.

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try making an array of all emailadresses like this

```
$emails = array($this->getEmails());
if(is_array($emails) && in_array($_POST["emailadres"],$emails))
{
// if we are here then it is not blacklisted
return true; // or whatever 
}
else
{
return false; // eighter it was a blacklisted email or the $emails wasnt an array  
}
```

Comment: could I make an array of blacklisted email addresses and use wildcards with domains?  the blacklist is way shorter than the whitelist.  For example I would want it to return false if the email was anything@competitor.com.

Answer (score 0):

Are you programming the form? If so, input validation? Not sure of the question here, but sounds like simple input validation.

Comment: yes, there is some validation going on.  It is Javascript validation of an HTML form.  I don't know how to do the blacklist part, however.